# How can I transfer the audio from my TV to my audio receiver with only an optical OUT and an RCA IN connection?

Tags: audio, hdmi

I have my computer connected to my LCD TV with HDMI to transfer audio and video. Now I would like to transfer the audio out from the TV to the audio in on my receiver. The problem is that my TV has only 1 audio out connection, which is optical, and the only audio in connections on the receiver are RCA or HDMI.

Is there a way for me to convert the signal between these two devices?

Comment: What TV and stereo receiver do you have?

Comment: The TV is an LG 47LH40. The receiver I did not buy, and I'm not currently at home so I can't find the specific model. It's a Philips receiver/DVD combination unit. Not sure if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:** 
OK, you've got SPDIF outputs on the TV, and analog stereo inputs on the receiver.  Do you have analog outputs on the computer?  (headphones, line out jack...)

If so, you've got the option:

- Follow sblair's answer, and hook the computer up to the receiver.  You may need to tweak your software to send audio out the stereo jacks instead of the HDMI.
- Get an SPDIF-to-stereo converter box to sit between the TV and the receiver.

Converting the SPDIF digital audio into analog stereo isn't a job for a simple adapter, you need a device like [this converter](http://www.ramelectronics.net/audio-video/audio-converters-extenders/analog-to-digital-digital-to-analog/dac-digital-to-analog-converter-gtv-digaud-2-aaud/prodGEF00232.html)[*]:

[image]

<sub>[*] For illustrative purposes only. Not an endorsement of this product or the store providing the URL.  This particular model only handles PCM, not DTS/bitstream digital signals.</sub>

---

**Original**:
Does the receiver have an HDMI output paired with its HDMI input?  If so, you could daisychain from computer -> receiver -> TV and stick with HDMI all the way.

What model is your receiver?  You mention having an RCA input on it; is it a digital input (single orange RCA) or analog stereo input (two RCA jacks, red & white)?  The device Bill Rodman's answer links to will only convert digital optical to digital coax, so it won't be useful for converting to analog inputs.

Comment: There is no HDMI output anywhere on the TV. The only output jack whatsoever that I can find is the optical audio out. The TV is an LG 47LH40, so if you know more than I do about LG TVs maybe I'm wrong. As far as the receiver, it's a Philips combination DVD/receiver but I don't have the model number. The RCA audio input is analog according to what you're saying.

Comment: Yeah that looks exactly like what I would need. Do you think there's any possibility of finding it cheaper somewhere or is $70 about the price I'm going to see everywhere? Thanks a lot.

Comment: i honestly don't know.  definitely shop around; maybe check with your local consumer electronics store to see what (if anything) they might carry.  check specs and watch out for uber-cheap ones; they might get the cost down by providing less features or using crappy components.

Comment: and remember the example i show above only works with LPCM digital, not AC3/DTS or other audio encodings that your TV might output.  one of those that does DTS decoding too might well run you $100+.

Answer (score 1):

If there's an analogue output on the computer (assuming the computer is the audio/video source), such as a speaker or headphone socket, then a standard 3.5mm jack to RCA cable may work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the RCA connection on your receiver is the single digital coax SPDIF input allowing for surround sound, you will need a device similar to the: [Toslink to RCA conveter](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10423&cs_id=1042302&p_id=2948&seq=1&format=2&style.).